# Combine two MySql databases, ORDER by date, But have different format

Tags: php, mysql

**Okay, before I begin, I must tell you that what I'm about to ask is very specific and extremely hard to explain, so I am going to give it my best shot to make it as clear and as simple as possible. Thank you.**

---

## Question:

I have two tables with two entirely different schemas, one called **mixtapes** and the other called **blabbing**. I want to be able to combine the two tables into one fetch, order them by date, but echo them out with entirely different formatting.

Imagine it as a mock-feed of facebook. Where everything is in different databases (image changes, posts, link posts, etc.), everything is ordered by date (if option is chosen) but they are all in different databases.


I want to stick to this formatting of mysql fetch array:

```
$sqlLatestActivity = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mixtapes WHERE posted_by_id
  IN ($array_of_subscribing);");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlLatestActivity)){ 
    $id = $row["id"];
    $title = $row["title"];
    $description = $row["description"];
    $keywords = $row["keywords"];
    $date = strtotime($row["date"]);
    $posted_by_id = $row["posted_by_id"];}
```

I want to fetch data from both tables, mixtapes & blabbing and combine it into one result of the 15 newest (by date) but formatted differently, for example:

if the result (one of the 15) is from mixtapes it should be formated like this:

```
$the_variable_echoing .= 
 '<div>'  . $posted_by_id . ' Just Added a Mixtape. To listen To it, go
 <a href="/THEMIXTAPE.php">here</a></div>';
```

however if it is a blab and the result is from blabbing, it should be formatted like this:

```
$the_variable_echoing .= '<div>' . $the_blab . '<br />
 Posted: ' . $blab_date . '</div>';
```

Than In my body I am going to add:

### `<?php echo $the_variable_echoing; ?>`

## Table Information

---

### *about:* **blabbing**;

id **(PRIMARY)**
Idofpage
poster_id **(The ID of the user posting the blab)**
date
the_blab
blab_type
device

### *about:* **mixtapes**;

id **(PRIMARY)**
title
if_featured
rating
genre
duration
number_of_tracks
description
keywords
date
posted_by_id
twitter_tags

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UNION` query and a judicious amount of *filler* columns (you didn't specify which columns you need from each table so I'm just taking a guess here). In order to support `WHERE` conditions, I'd also make this a view, eg

```
CREATE VIEW `feed` AS
SELECT
    id,
    title,
    description,
    keywords,
    `date`,
    posted_by_id,
    'mixtape' AS `type`
FROM mixtapes
UNION ALL
SELECT
    id,
    the_blab AS title, 
    device AS description, -- use device in the description column
    null AS keywords, -- this will be blank
    `date`,
    poster_id AS posted_by_id,
    'blab' AS `type`
FROM blabbing;
```

Then `SELECT` using

```
SELECT * FROM `feed` WHERE `posted_by_id` IN (?, ?, ?)
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 15
```

You just need to ensure that the two combined `SELECT` statements have matching column numbers and types.

Each row in the result set will have a `type` column with either `mixtape` or `blab` value so you can determine which table it's from.

Example rendering (PDO, use it!)

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `feed` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15');
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
    <div>
    <?php if ($row['type'] == 'mixtape') : ?>
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['posted_by_id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>
        Just Added a Mixtape. To listen To it, go
        <a href="/THEMIXTAPE.php">here</a>
    <?php elseif ($row['type'] == 'blab') : ?>
        <!-- echo title as this is the the_blab alias in the view -->
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>
        <br />
        Posted: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['date'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

---

As a consideration that involves more querying (but hey, it's only 15 records in total). I'd probably just go with something like this

```
SELECT `id`, `date`, 'mixtape' AS `type` FROM mixtapes
UNION ALL
SELECT `id`, `date`, 'blab' AS `type` FROM blabbing
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Now you have the id and source table for the latest fifteen entries across the two tables. As you iterate the result set, I'd simply query the appropriate table by ID for the complete set of data for that record. Given appropriate caching, this should perform fairly well and would be much easier to understand.

You might also consider a non-relational database (Mongo, CouchDB, etc) as it may be more appropriate for the task.

Comment: I don't understand how to merge them into echoing into a page. I know a very slight bit of how to merge in fetching, but I am looking more to find out how to echo in different format.

Comment: @AlexSarnowski I've updated my answer with a rendering example

Comment: Thank you for the help, however I have to add that this isn't what I was looking for. I am doing this all through a PHP page and I want to pack everything into variables so that I can use a single echo $variable in my BODY tag (to render out all 15). I was hoping to complete all of the IF ELSE, etc. functions before the page begins (in head). Also I don't exactly understand where to put that whole entire first block of code you gave me, as I am new to PHP/MYSQL.